# how to replace a file with an other?

Tags: c, file-io

I am writing a simple encryption program, that takes any given file, writes encrypted data to a temporary file and I am now looking for the most efficient way to replace the original file with its encrypted counterpart.

I know I could just fopen the original with w and copy line by line the encrypted file, but I was wondering if there was any more efficient way to do it, like overwriting the original file hard-link to point to the ciphered file sparing me the need to rewrite the entirety of the file?

Comment: How about the obvious suggestion of using `rename()`?

Comment: if you are on linux and your two file are on the same mounted filesystem, then just use "rename". I would like to point out that having the temporary file and the final file on the same directory will save you some headache thank to the fact that the two file will be on the same file systeme and rename will act "atomicaly" in that case. (you don't wan't to have your file copy being cut in the middle, ending with a destination file not being ok).

Comment: so renaming tmp file will overwrite the original one?

Comment: @Balocre How about reading the doc ?

Comment: Let's suppose you want to encrypt file FOO. Pseudo code: 1. copy FOO to TEMP while encrypring. 2. [Delete](https://linux.die.net/man/3/remove) FOO. 3. [Rename](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rename) TEMP to FOO.

Answer (score 1):

on linux, you could use `mv`.

And if the two files are not in the same directory, `mv` would be the better choice for several reasons, including that an option can be given to `mv` so no prompt output when a file is overwritten I.E

```
mv -f tempfile original_newfile
```

the result will be that `tempfile` no longer exists and the original file now contains the tempfile with the original name

Note: `mv` manipulates the 'hardlinks' to do its work

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Chris-Turner and explained by @Jabberwocky using rename works fine